# Overriding the Update method of Django queryset

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

As part of one of the requirement, we are overriding the Update method in the custom Queryset.

Sample code is as follows.

```
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class PollQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Some Business Logic

        # Call super to continue the flow -- from below line we are unable to invoke super
        super().update(*args, **kwargs)

class Question(models.Model):
    objects = PollQuerySet.as_manager()

    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

It is unable to invoke update in base Queryset from the Custom Queryset.

> TypeError at /polls/
> must be type, not PollQuerySet

Any solution is much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, you are unable to call the update method in the super class. if so that's because you are calling it wrong. Here is how:

```
super(PollQuerySet,self).update(*args, **kwargs)
```

In the case of python 3.x the class name and self become optional parameters. So the above line can be shortened to

```
super().update(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Question tagged with python3 so, `super().update(*args, **kwargs)`. :)